# Openstack TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/networks/

Tags: python, django

There is a TemplateSyntaxError in horizon. I don not change anything in this model. All of the code is:

```
    {% load i18n %}
{% with table.needs_form_wrapper as needs_form_wrapper %}
<div class="table_wrapper">
  {% if needs_form_wrapper %}<form action="{{ table.get_absolute_url }}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}{% endif %}
  {% with columns=table.get_columns rows=table.get_rows %}
{% block table %}
  <table id="{{ table.name }}" class="table table-bordered table-striped datatable">
    <thead>
  {% block table_caption %}
      <tr class='table_caption'>
        <th class='table_header' colspan='{{ columns|length }}'>
          <h3 class='table_title'>{{ table }}</h3>
          {{ table.render_table_actions }}
        </th>
      </tr>
  {% endblock table_caption %}
  {% block table_breadcrumb %}
      {% if table.breadcrumb %}
        <tr>
          <td class="breadcrumb_td" colspan="{{ table.get_columns|length }}">
            {{ table.breadcrumb.render }}
          </td>
        </tr>
      {% endif %}
  {% endblock table_breadcrumb %}
  {% block table_columns %}
      {% if not table.is_browser_table %}
      <tr>
        {% for column in columns %}
          <th {{ column.attr_string|safe }}>{{ column }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
      {% endif %}
  {% endblock table_columns %}
    </thead>
  {% block table_body %}
    <tbody>
    {% for row in rows %}
      {{ row.render }}
    {% empty %}
    <tr class="{% cycle 'odd' 'even' %} empty">
      <td colspan="{{ table.get_columns|length }}">{{ table.get_empty_message }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  {% endblock table_body %}
  {% block table_footer %}
    {% if table.footer %}
    <tfoot>
      {% if table.needs_summary_row %}
      <tr class="summation">
        {% for column in columns %}
          {% if forloop.first %}
          <td>{% trans "Summary" %}</td>
          {% else %}
          <td>{{ column.get_summation|default_if_none:"&ndash;"}}</td>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
      {% endif %}
      <tr>
        <td colspan="{{ table.get_columns|length }}">
          <span class="table_count">{% blocktrans count counter=rows|length %}Displaying {{ counter }} item{% plural %}Displaying {{ counter }} items{% endblocktrans %}</span>
          {% if table.has_more_data %}
          <span class="spacer">|</span>
          <a href="?{{ table.get_pagination_string }}">More&nbsp;&raquo;</a>
          {% endif %}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    {% endif %}
  {% endblock table_footer %}
  </table>
{% endblock table %}
  {% endwith %}
  {% if needs_form_wrapper %}</form>{% endif %}
</div>
{% endwith %}
```

error at " {% with columns=table.get_columns rows=table.get_rows %} ". Is there anything wrong ??? My django version is 1.4.8

Comment: post some of the error text.

Comment: It only says "TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/networks/project/networks/_network_ips.html". . .

Comment: I can't see in the code, but you are ending all you tags correct? Like `{% endwith %}`, `{% endblock %}`

Comment: All of the above code has already writen. Please have a look at on it . Thank you

Comment: Is this `django-tables2`? Can you get the stack trace? Is `DEBUG=True`?